# Return error message to a database field: Yii2 and Swiftmailer

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

I program in PHP using the **Yii2** framework and **Swiftmailer**.

I am trying to find a way to update a database field with error messages. When a user is trying to create an account, and the email he declares is not a valid one, the field **FailMesg** should be updated with the error message.
I have tried two different ways to do it but none seems to work (the database field remains NULL):

**1st ( Include variable in send() method)**

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->………..
$transport = ………………
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
if($mailer->send($message, $failures)){
    ……..
else
    ……..
    $user->FailMesg = $failures;
........
$user->save();
```

**2nd (Use the Logger plugin)**

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->………..
$transport = ………………
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$logger = new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
$mailer->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));
if($mailer->send($message)){
    ……..
else
    ……..
    $user->FailMesg = $logger->dump();
........
$user->save();
```

Am I missing something here? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: From your provided code sample I cannot see you calling `user->save()` to actually save the value of `$user->FailMesg` into the DB. I am assuming that `$user` is an object of `User` model and the FailMesg` field exists in the corresponding `user` table.

Comment: You are assuming correctly. Of course I include a `$user->save()` command, just forgot to include, sorry, I will edit the initial question. - @sm1979

Comment: Could you include your `rules`? Validation might be getting in the way of your save.

Comment: @topher I assume you are asking about **FailMesg** field: in database (SQL Server) it is defined as datatype **nvarchar(MAX)**. In the Yii2 model the only rule it is applied on it is: **string**.

Comment: @topher Due to your remark, I also defined the **FailMesg** field as '**safe**' but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

`$failures` is an array, not a string. From the [swiftmailer docs](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#getting-failures-by-reference):

> If the variable name does not yet exist, it will be initialized as an empty array and then failures will be added to that array. If the variable already exists it will be type-cast to an array and failures will be added to it.

You have to change it into a string before saving e.g.:

```
$user->FailMesg = implode("|", $failures);
```

Comment: You are totally right about this, thank you. But the problem still remains! @topher

Comment: If a validation error is occurring, dump the contents of `$user->getErrors()`